# Getting error while installing the ubuntu in VMWare

Tags: vmware

The `vmware` shows the error:

```
"Intel VT-x might be disabled if it has been disabled in the BIOS/firmware settings or the host has not been power-cycled since changing this setting."
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to know whether or not you'll be needing the Intel hardware virtualization feature enabled for the Ubuntu OS?

If not, you can ignore that message.

If so, you can enable it with the following:
With the system powered off, go into VM > Settings > Hardware tab, choose Processors from the hardware list, and check "Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT"